# How to do Doubleclick Element on SAP GUIShell using Robot Framework?

Tags: robotframework, sap-gui

I am trying to automate my work in SAP using the Robot Framework with the SapGuiLibrary, but at the moment I’m having difficulties executing the *Doubleclick Element* command on a shell object.

After inspecting the object with Script Tracker I found the lines below:

```
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell").setCurrentCell 2,"STRAS"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell").selectedRows = "2"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell").doubleClickCurrentCell
```

The command asks for 3 parameters:

```
Doubleclick Element    element_id    item_id    column_id
```

So I put like this:

```
Doubleclick Element    wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell    2    STRAS
```

But it dind't work as you can see below:

```
AttributeError: <unknown>.doubleClickItem
```

So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a current limitation of SapGuiLibrary.

The keyword `DoubleClick Element` is only for double clicking an item in a **Tree** control of type "List" or "Column" (object `GuiTree`).

In your case, you want to double-click a cell in a **Grid** control (object `GuiGridView`), but SapGuiLibrary doesn't propose a keyword for that.

Either you file a bug at https://github.com/frankvanderkuur/robotframework-sapguilibrary/issues, or you do the correction yourself.

NB: if you're a developer, you may see all the limitations by comparing the [SapGuiLibrary code](https://github.com/frankvanderkuur/robotframework-sapguilibrary/blob/master/SapGuiLibrary/SapGuiLibrary.py) and all possible [SAP GUI Scripting objects and methods](https://help.sap.com/viewer/product/sap_gui_for_windows/latest/en-US?q=SAP+GUI+Scripting+API) (use this [direct link](https://help.sap.com/viewer/b47d018c3b9b45e897faf66a6c0885a8/760.05/en-US) if the search hangs).